# How to change background color of textblock on editing?

Tags: gojs

By default, in GoJs, when user tries to edit text in textblock of gojs, white background appears. I need to change this white color to some different color. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This was originally answered at https://forum.nwoods.com/t/how-to-change-backgound-color-of-textblock-on-editing/10008.

First, become familiar with TextEditingTool and HTMLInfo:
https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/TextEditingTool.html
https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/HTMLInfo.html

In particular, note that you want to modify https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/HTMLInfo.html#mainElement.

And you can get the default HTMLInfo at 
https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/TextEditingTool.html#defaultTextEditor.

And like all tools, you can get the default TextEditingTool at https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/ToolManager.html#textEditingTool.

So one way to do it is to define your own CSS class:

```
<style>
  .myTextEditorCSSClass {
    background: magenta;
  }
</style>
```

and then right after your Diagram initialization:

```
myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, ...)

var tool = myDiagram.toolManager.textEditingTool;
tool.defaultTextEditor.mainElement.className = "myTextEditorCSSClass";
```

[image: text editor background]